# How to convert a base64 image to blob or dataURL in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to convert image taken from camera to blob to pass in Face API detect face api as [binary data] input

(https://[location].api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect[?returnFaceId][&returnFaceLandmarks][&returnFaceAttributes])

However unable to convert the base64Image to blob and idea?

Comment: I think you will have use the `nativescript-background-http` plugin here to upload the image for face detection.

Answer (score 2):

Blob is data object in Javascript. Unless you need to send your data via webview, you cannot convert a base64 string to Blob in NativeScript. In javascript, it's simply create a new Blob with base64 string, e.g. [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVBJYZ?editors=1111)

```
var mediaFile = new Blob([_base64], {
  type: 'data:image/png;base64',
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding': 'base64'
});
```

But you can just send binary data to Face API with NSData.

Comment: Thanks let me try this, I have tried the btoa approach however it will not work as there is no DOM element.